# Intel 8265 doesn't work in Loki

Tags: wifi, intel

I just purchased a 2016 hp specter x360 (7th gen Intel) that comes equipped with an Intel 8265 dual band wifi (https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi).

In the initial installation I noticed that the wireless wasn't coming up after reboot. So I took a look in /lib/firmware and confirmed that the 8265 firmware were not present.

I managed to track down a USB wireless dongle (Belkin/Realtek) to get myself online and performed the standard system updates. That brought me from kernel 4.4.38 to 4.4.57-generic.

Now when I look at /lib/firmware I do in fact see that 8265 firwmare is included. My heart skips a beat because now my wifi adapater should work, right?

Well, reboot and poof. Nada. It just doesn't come up. It is recognized by the system I believe (01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 24fd (rev 78)):

```
 lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 5904 (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 5916 (rev 02)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 02)
00:13.0 Non-VGA unclassified device: Intel Corporation Device 9d35 (rev 21)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d11 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d18 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d58 (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 9d71 (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 24fd (rev 78)
6d:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device a804
```

depmod doesn't show my the firmware is loaded at all.

I can confirm that this wifi chip works perfectly fine in Ubuntu 16.10 and Ubuntu Mate 16.10.

Any thoughts on how I can get it enabled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See if `sudo apt-get install linux-generic-hwe-16.04-edge` gets the 4.8 kernel installed and then do

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.161.1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware_1.161.1_all.deb
```

Reboot

Comment: This also fixed my Intel 8260 bluetooth issue (not working)! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just as completion to Jeremy31 post. On this date, when I tried using the fix, the apt-get command installs the 4.10 kernel, not 4.8. The WiFi somewhat works. I used the original firmware in that post and the 1.165 one from the same link folder. They both work pretty much the same. The WiFi is functional, but it has a big loading time for web pages. I do not know if this is because it has some drops or anything else.

P.S. I used an answer, and not a comment, because my reputation is too low. Maybe worth mentioning: I have a Clevo P650 . Maybe guys buying the same hardware find this thread faster this way.