# XORG issue from frozen trackpad - crumb!

Tags: boot, wifi, touchpad

Good morning,

Running Loki w/ 4.8.0-34-generic kernel on a 2016 HP Spectre x360 w/ edge drivers loaded (so I can get my wifi to work; [Intel 8265 doesn't work in Loki](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/9874/intel-8265-doesnt-work-in-loki)).

Last night I left the OS running, I closed the lid and went to bed. This morning when I opened the lid I was at the login prompt (GUI). Trackpad is dead. So, I toggled by input switching device (this allows me to share keyboard and mouse across multiple devices via USB) so that I could access my external mouse. This worked.

I logged in and everything was fine. Being the curious type, I started to try and figure out how to resolve this lip-closed/open and frozen trackpad. Inevitably I found myself at the console via ctrl-alt+F1. I didn't make any changes, just flipped to console.

Like and **idiot** instead of just flipping back to GUI login via ctrl-alt+F7, I issued a 'sudo startx' command and got that awesome error. You know the one? That startx is deprecated because it's not safe or whatever.

Anyway, now my system is totally jacked. I cannot login via GUI even after reboot. System presents login, I give password and it acts like it's trying to go to desktop but it never does. Just loops me back to login screen.

cat of Xorg.0.log gives me:

533.404 (II) XINPUT: adding extended input device "ELAN0732:00 04F3:249E" (type: touchscreen, id 10)

Nothing else. And, my wifi card won't come up so I can't even do a re-install on XORG. I've tried raising the device via 'iwconfig' to no avail.

Any ideas where to go from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the answer to my problem had to do with .xAuthority being given to root as opposed to my username.

This AskUbuntu post solved it: https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop