# Wifi Disabled with Intel Wireless Adapter 8265

Tags: wifi, intel

I recently install ElementaryOS and have spent hours trying to get wireless enabled. I have a Toshiba Satellite L55 and went into Bios and enabled wifi power. Any information you need to help me, I will provide. Thank you, I would really like to use ElementaryOS.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check in terminal with command uname -a what kernel version do you have. If newer then ignore the solution below and download drivers from Intel provided in the second link.

Solution from here: [Intel 8265 doesn't work in Loki](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/9874/intel-8265-doesnt-work-in-loki)

See if sudo apt-get install linux-generic-hwe-16.04-edge gets the 4.8 kernel installed and then do

wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.161.1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware_1.161.1_all.deb

Also drivers from Intel can be downloaded here: [Linux* Support for Intel® Wireless Adapters](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-io/wireless-networking.html)